# How realistic is a 4 ports charging only USB hub mount inside a wall outlet box?

Tags: power-supply, power, usb, heat

[Here's a concept](http://www.artlebedev.com/everything/hi-res/zaryadkus/) of a wall outlet variation. It's size of a wall outlet (occupies the same size standard box in a wall) but instead of mains outlet it has four USB ports for charging various devices.

Now this thing would have to contain a power supply that would convert mains AC into low voltage DC and it would have to support all flavors of protocols for fast charging so that ports are not limited to 0,5 amperes.

The problem is such power supply would dissipate quite a lot of heat (like several watts) as by-product and this heat would need to somehow be dissipated which is rather problematic for a device mount inside wall.

How realistic is this setup in terms of dissipating heat produced by the power supply?

Comment: I must say I love the idea of leaving my $500+ tablet and $300+ cell phone sitting unprotected on the floor to charge...

Comment: Sounds like you could use a small $20+ table.

Comment: @Jim Paris: LOL - waiting for "charging table for iPhone" offers starting at $399.

Answer (score 5):

Entirely viable. 
Eben if you had 2A x 4 ports x 5V = 40 Watts you should be able to get 80% efficiency or 8 watts dissipation. 8 Watts (or even 20W) is able to be dissipated either into air space around box or, if needed, via a metal faceplate. 2A x 4 would be extreme probably and you'd usually have much less heat to deal with.

Comment: There's no guaranteed "air space" around the box - it will be whatever happens to be in the wall, but using the face plate sounds realistic.

Answer (score 2):

Is so realistic that there are [commercial products](http://www.i-socket.net/) available

Comment: Well, it doesn't look available - the price is zero and I'd guess `PRODOTTO IN ARRIVO` means "not available, pending".

Comment: True (price is 18.something €). That was only the first link I found. I actually have two USB charger in a wall-mounted electrical box. They're single-port, with 2A available. Look on the bticino catalog, first item in this page http://www.lecchiimpianti.it/lecchiimpianti/files/2011/12/Caricabatterie-USB.png

Comment: They are common and readily available: [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=usb+wall+outlet), [Google Shopper](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=shop&q=usb+wall+outlet&oq=usb+wall+outlet), etc.